# Counting Occurrences in a tree

Tags: java, tree

I can't seem to find the answer to my problem so here I am. I have a tree that has been filled in with strings from a file and need to count how many times a string is seen. So everything works fine except me counting the strings right.
So here is the code where I attempt to count the occurrences of each string.

```
/* Function for postorder traversal */
public void postorder(Scanner file)
{
    postorder(root,file);
}

private void postorder(BSTNode r,Scanner file)
{
    int counter = 0;
    String key;
    if (r != null)
    {
        key = file.next();
        postorder(r.getLeft(),file);
        postorder(r.getRight(),file);
        if(key.compareTo(r.getData()) == 0)
        {
            counter++;
        }
    System.out.println(r.getData() +", " + counter); 
    }
}
```

If it'll help this is the output to the console I'm getting:

```
McGurkus, 0 
Kircus, 0
call, 0
I'll, 0
I, 0
circus, 0
it, 0
my, 0
for, 0
put, 0
tents, 0
think, 0
the, 0
up, 0
to, 0
ready, 1
All, 1
```

Everything is supposed to be 1. Any help or guidance to where I can derive the solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Might need to see a bit more code here, for example, what data type does `r.getData()` return? (Move the `println` one line above to inside the second level `if` block maybe??? ) What does the input file look like?

Comment: Obviously, there's something wrong with the comparing, which is not returning zero and therefore not incrementing `counter` leaving you with `counter` equal to zero. I'd start debugging by observing what `key` is.

Comment: @BretC `r.getData()` obviously is the content of the node (type `String`) @Adriel dwood i guess the issue is that the tree is differently generated from the file, than you read it in your postorder method. could you please post the method to generate the tree

Comment: @Paul Just checking ;)

Comment: your are iterating the file keys while traversing the tree: you will only get matches if the tree has been populated in the same DFS order as it is read here; what your method does is checking if the tree and file are the same data. If you want to count occurrences, you need to use a Map<String,Integer> (key,count)

Comment: Yeah guess I overlooked that flaw, pretty obvious now that you pointed it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tree already has the data, and you're traversing the tree to find the frequency of each word, what do you need the file for?

I don't know what you're requirement is, but I would suggest keeping a data structure (say a Map) on the class where the key is the word and the value is the frequency which you update whenever you look on a tree node.

Something like:

private Map map = new HashMap();

```
 private void postorder(BSTNode r)
 {
     String key;
     if (r != null)
     {
         key = r.getData();
         if(map.containsKey(key)){
            Integer value = (Integer)map.get(key);
            map.put(key, ++value);
         }
         postorder(r.getLeft(),file);
         postorder(r.getRight(),file);

         System.out.println(r.getData() +", " + counter); 
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yeah I understand what you are saying, I tried it and it worked. Thanks for the input guys. This was bothering me a lot.